How to have 5 different always-on-top notes, one on each screen?
Screen as in the different desktops in mac os
I'm using macOS and I frequently work with multiple spaces. I'm looking for a way to have 5 different notes or quick notes that are always on top of all my other windows, with one note on each of my spaces. I want to be able to quickly jot down information or refer to important notes without having to switch between windows, applications, or spaces.
Ideally, the solution should have the following features:

Each note should be always on top, so it remains visible even when I'm working on other windows or applications within the same space.
I should be able to position one note on each of my spaces.
The notes should be easily accessible and allow me to quickly input or view information.
It would be great if the notes support basic formatting like bold, italic, and lists.
The ability to save and load notes would be a plus.

I'm open to using any software or tools that can achieve this functionality. It could be a dedicated note-taking application, a customizable widget, or even a combination of different tools.
I'm using the latest version of macOS.
If anyone has any suggestions, recommendations, or step-by-step instructions on how to set this up, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

You can do all this in Apple Notes.

Notes has the ability to open any note in a new window. In the list of notes, right-click (Control-click) on a note and use "Open Note in a New Window".
Each note can be set on top from the Notes menus with Windows > Keep on Top.
Move each note to whatever space you want - just as you would move any window.
Each note will be instantly accessible since it can be on top.
Apple Notes supports formatting.
Apple Notes automatically saves notes.  To load a new note, you would have to return to the initial Notes window with its list of available notes.

You should try this method before embarking on purchasing the perfect notes like app.
Many note taking apps have similar abilities - I use Typora which is a markdown editor.
For a simpler experience use Stickies (also part of macOS). It also has the features you require:

Always on top (and can be translucent).
Move to different spaces.
Available all the time on its desktop.
Rich text formatting.
Notes are saved within the app, can be exported or copy/paste to more permanent storage.

As with Apple Notes, there are alternatives from the App Store - you might want to look at Popnote or, for a different usage, Tot.

notes do not stay on their assigned spaces
